# I can connect github through a webbrower but not a shell or window subsystem linux (WSL)

Tags: networking, command-line, server, dns, windows-subsystem-for-linux

For some reason I can access github.com through a regular webbrower like Chrome, but not Windows PowerShell or WSL. I've highlighted tracert which I think may be important.

Here are some outputs from the shells.

PowerShell:

```
PS C:\Users\rlf> ping github.com \
Pinging github.com [20.205.243.166] with 32 bytes of data:\
Request timed out.\
Request timed out.\
Request timed out.\
Request timed out.\
Ping statistics for 20.205.243.166:\
Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss)
```

**tracert from PowerShell:**

```
PS C:\Users\rlf> tracert github.com\
Tracing route to github.com [20.205.243.166]\
over a maximum of 30 hops:\
1    35 ms    34 ms    35 ms  10.35.14.1\
2     *        *        *     Request timed out.\
3    55 ms    57 ms   124 ms  10.227.138.254\
4     *       37 ms    38 ms  192.254.91.72\
5    72 ms    61 ms   117 ms  104.254.117.84\
6    35 ms    37 ms    35 ms  104.254.114.160\
7    66 ms    40 ms    38 ms  192.254.81.111\
8    36 ms    39 ms    39 ms  8075.hkg.equinix.com [36.255.56.4]\
9    82 ms    35 ms    36 ms  ae27-0.icr01.hkg31.ntwk.msn.net [104.44.42.176]\
10    67 ms    68 ms    68 ms  be-100-0.ibr01.hkg31.ntwk.msn.net [104.44.11.125]\
11    66 ms     *      174 ms  be-3-0.ibr01.sg2.ntwk.msn.net [104.44.29.0]\
12    65 ms    66 ms    66 ms  ae102-0.icr02.sg2.ntwk.msn.net [104.44.11.184]\
13     *        *        *     Request timed out.\
14     *        *        *     Request timed out.\
15     *        *        *     Request timed out.\
16     *        *        *     Request timed out.\
17     *        *        *     Request timed out.\
18     *        *        *     Request timed out.                                                                       19     *        *        *     Request timed out.                                                                       20     *        *        *     Request timed out.                                                                       21     *        *        *     Request timed out.                                                                       22     *        *        *     Request timed out.                                                                       23     *        *        *     Request timed out.                                                                       24     *        *        *     Request timed out.                                                                       25     *        *        *     Request timed out.                                                                       26     *        *        *     Request timed out.                                                                       27     *        *        *     Request timed out.                                                                       28     *        *        *     Request timed out.                                                                       29     *        *        *     Request timed out.                                                                       30     *        *        *     Request timed out.                                                                                                                                                                                              Trace complete.
```

WSL:

```
(research) rlf@-RLF:~$ ping github.com\
ping: github.com: Temporary failure in name resolution                                            


(research) rlf@-RLF:~$ nslookup github.com \
Server:         172.18.208.1 \
Address:        172.18.208.1#53\
Non-authoritative answer:\
Name:   github.com\
Address: 20.205.243.166\
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

Adding things for pinging google.com

```
PS C:\Users\rlf> ping google.com \
Pinging google.com [172.217.27.46] with 32 bytes of data:\
Reply from 172.217.27.46: bytes=32 time=37ms TTL=113\
Reply from 172.217.27.46: bytes=32 time=37ms TTL=113\
Reply from 172.217.27.46: bytes=32 time=36ms TTL=113\
Reply from 172.217.27.46: bytes=32 time=39ms TTL=113\
Ping statistics for 172.217.27.46:\
Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),\
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:\
Minimum = 36ms, Maximum = 39ms, Average = 37ms\
```

```
(research) rlf@-RLF:~$ nslookup google.com\
Server:         172.18.208.1\
Address:        172.18.208.1#53\
Non-authoritative answer:\
Name:   google.com\
Address: 172.217.27.46\
Name:   google.com\
Address: 2404:6800:4005:808::200e
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  While I do try to help on WSL questions here, the network failures in PowerShell seem to indicate that this is almost all but certain to be a problem on the Windows side (or further up the network).  It would probably be better to delete this here and repost it on [Super User](https://superuser.com).

Comment: Also be sure to include as much information as you can about your network -- Is it a home network?  Corporate?  On a VPN?  The more information the Stack Exchange community (be it here on Ask Ubuntu or on Super User) has, the better the chance someone will be able to help you.